# DB:Migrate for Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, sqlite, heroku

I am working in Ruby on Rails.

I am updating a database with users locally:

- Using the "rails console"
- Running rails server
- Checking on localhost:3000

The users are added on my local host.

I then try and run steps 3-7

1. Make changes to local code
2. Run any migrations LOCALLY
3. Add all changed files to Git git add .
4. Commit all added files to git git commit -m "Adding features"
5. Push the changes to Heroku git push heroku master - assuming you are using heroku as your remote name and you are working in the master branch
6. If you have migrations run heroku run rake db:migrate to run the migrations ON HEROKU
7. Following migrations do heroku restart

After step 6 I get this as a result:

```
"Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.5819
Migrating to CreateUsers (20140812155921)
== 20140812155921 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0572s
== 20140812155921 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0574s) =============================

Migrating to AddIndexToUsersEmail (20140812200300)
== 20140812200300 AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrating =============================
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0252s
== 20140812200300 AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrated (0.0254s) ====================

Migrating to AddPasswordDigestToUsers (20140812204144)
== 20140812204144 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating =========================
-- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)
   -> 0.0039s
== 20140812204144 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrated (0.0041s) ================

Migrating to AddRememberTokenToUsers (20140814171549)
== 20140814171549 AddRememberTokenToUsers: migrating ==========================
-- add_column(:users, :remember_token, :string)
   -> 0.0067s
-- add_index(:users, :remember_token)
   -> 0.0171s
== 20140814171549 AddRememberTokenToUsers: migrated (0.0275s) =================

Migrating to AddAdminToUsers (20140815204326)
== 20140815204326 AddAdminToUsers: migrating ==================================
-- add_column(:users, :admin, :boolean, {:default=>false})
   -> 0.0963s
== 20140815204326 AddAdminToUsers: migrated (0.0977s) =========================

Migrating to CreateMicroposts (20140815212754)
== 20140815212754 CreateMicroposts: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:microposts)
   -> 0.0256s
-- add_index(:microposts, [:user_id, :created_at])
   -> 0.0350s
== 20140815212754 CreateMicroposts: migrated (0.0611s) ========================

Migrating to CreateRelationships (20140816000750)
== 20140816000750 CreateRelationships: migrating ==============================
-- create_table(:relationships)
   -> 0.0217s
-- add_index(:relationships, :follower_id)
   -> 0.0385s
-- add_index(:relationships, :followed_id)
   -> 0.0195s
-- add_index(:relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0226s
== 20140816000750 CreateRelationships: migrated (0.1057s) ====================="
```

When I do: 
heroku open

and try to log in it now says my user information is invalid and heroku support says there are no user records.

Does anyone know what I can do here?  This folder was also copied over from another project I was working on, so I deleted the .git file and created a new repository.  I just don't know why my database will work locally but not on heroku.

Thanks much.

Best,
David

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean exactly, are you expecting the locally created users to be uploaded to the server when you deploy?

Comment: Hello Mohammad, yeah I want to be able to locally create 10 pre populated users.  Then when I deploy it have those 10 users be populated.  Currently the 10 users will only be populated locally and not on the heroku site.

Comment: check my seeds answer

Answer (score 1):

The users you are creating are stored in your local database only. When you push to Heroku you need to create the users in the Heroku database, either through your user registration interface or through a seeds file.

Comment: how do I create it through a seed file?  I've been reading that there is a way to transfer it but not if my database is sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample seed file that you might want to push

```
# /db/seeds.rb
User.where(email: 'admin@domain.com').first_or_create! do |user|
  user.name = 'admin'
  user.password = 'temporarypassword'
end
```

Then push this to the server and run the seeds, you'll need to login and change the password as soon as possible, since the password is pushed into the version control.